# Dismissing a presented UINavigationController in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

In my root UIViewController I present a UINavigationController.  The UINavigationController ultimately pushes another view (let's call it MyViewController).  How can I dismiss the entire UINavigationController (and the views it has pushed) from MyViewController?

From MyViewController, I've tried calling `[[self.navigationController presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]` but nothing happend.  I've also tried first popping all the view controllers off the navigation controller but, still, the navigation controller was not dismissed.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:

I've tracked down what's causing this issue but haven't been able to solve it.  The UINavigationController described above is a custom subclass of UIImagePickerController (we'll call it CameraController) with source type UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera.  Everything works as expected (using the answer provided below) until I set a custom `cameraOverlayView` on the CameraController in `viewDidLoad`.  Commenting out the following lines gets things working:

```
self.showCameraControls = NO;
UIView *overlay = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CameraController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```

Comment: how do you present the navigation controller? how do you switch from uiview to navigation? modal ? if so `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` should work

Comment: I'm doing `[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:NO completion:nil]`.  The modal stuff is deprecated in iOS6.

Comment: "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller."  Did you try calling `dismissViewController` just on the navigation controller itself?  Also, are you sure `self.navigationController` isn't nil?

Comment: on your navController's first viewController can you NSLog `[self presentingViewController]` and `[self.navigationController presentingViewController]` ... do they both return the same object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO` on your `self.navigationController` itself.

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: No.  I'm going to try this on a fresh project with nothing but what I described above to make sure there's nothing else interfering.

Comment: Have you tried printing `self.navigationController`? Is it nil?

Comment: Yes. It is not nil.  It is an instance of a UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Do you have a UIImagePickerController displayed as modal? From where are you calling the above code then?

Comment: Not sure what a model view is...perhaps you meant modal.  I am calling `dismissViewController` from an IBAction in MyViewController (a view controller that was pushed onto the UIImagePickerController/UINavigationController).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23251/discussion-between-acb-and-scttnlsn)

Comment: I must have been overlooking something in my original example.  When I rebuilt a simplified version this answer did the trick.

Comment: just logged [self presentingViewController] before and after calling [self.navigationController dismiss...]. Before dismissing it was my root view controller, the second time it was null

Comment: @scttnlsn, Do you mean to say that `[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` is not working in iPhone 5? In that case you might have to access rootiviewcontroller and call a method in that which will dismiss the imagepicker from that class.